Does the Snort inline mode work with windows?
I am not sure if the snort inline mode works with Windows. Is it right, that Snort isn‘t a intrusion prevention system without the inline mode?
I saw multiple Videos an blogs about inline mode in Linux and Unix-based systems, but not for Windows.
